# (C Linux) strftime returns corrupt date time

Tags: c, linux, time

I am using following code:

```
char dateModified[101];
setlocale(LC_TIME, "en_US.UTF-8");
    //Get address for the file's modified time:
struct timespec *timeP = &(filesList[i].mtime);
    //Translate the time to text
strftime(dateModified, 100, "%b %e %Y %R", timeP);
    //Print time since 1970, address of the struct and formatted time
printf("%d %d \'%s\'\n", timeP->tv_sec, timeP, dateModified);
```

to format and print last modified time for multiple files. However, even though the timestamp is correct, the formatted time is always incorrect.
What could be the problem?
Output for some files:

```
TIMESTAMP  ADDRESS   FORMATTED TIME
1494268890 15343728 '?  0 1852401361 74573639:00'
1494268890 15344048 '?  0 1701605586 74573639:00'
1494268890 15344368 '?  0 1885498010 74573639:00'
1494268889 15344688 '?  0 1900 130561033:00'
```

(All timestamps point to May 08th 2017, 6:41pm (UTC))

Comment: Note: neither `timeP->tv_sec` nor `timeP` are of type `int` as required by the `printf` format spec `%d`.

Comment: yep, fixed tv_sec to long. as for timeP, i just wanted to see the address, this line isnt going to stay in code.

Comment: For an address: `printf("%p", (void*)timeP);`

Comment: Please do not edit your posted code which will confuse anyone following comments. `%l` is not a valid format specifier.

Comment: ok, so `printf("%ld %p \'%s\'\n", timeP->tv_sec, (void *) timeP, dateModified);` should be correct?

Comment: I do not know. There is no [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which I an copy paste and compile.

Comment: I think "timespec" is the wrong type for: size_t strftime(char *, size_t, const char *, const struct tm *);

Comment: seems like the problem, thanks!